# Unable to import OpenAIEmbedding from llama_index.embeddings

Tags: llama-index, openaiembeddings

ImportError: cannot import name 'OpenAIEmbedding' from 'llama_index.embeddings' (unknown location)
I get this error both while working on googlecolab as well as jupyter notebook. I had a similar issue with importing SimpleDirectoryReader importing from llama_index. That was resolved by adding llama_index.core

I tired to resolve it by installing the previous version ie 0.9.48
Was expecting code to run.
Is this depricated?